# Downloading mp3 from mp3clan.audio with C#

Tags: c#, audio, download, mp3

I'm having headaches to make this work, is a mp3 downloader which downloads songs from mp3clan and other websites. here's my download code:

```
 public void StartDownload()
    {
        downloadMusicGuid = dwMp3Skull.GenerateUniqueGuid();

        streamToWriteTo = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("music/" + downloadMusicGuid + ".mp3", FileMode.Create, file);

            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            request.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetData), request);

    }



    void GetData(IAsyncResult result)
    { 

      try
      {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);             

        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => fSize = BytesToString(response.ContentLength)));

        Stream rStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        byte[] data = new byte[16 * 1024];
        int read;

        long totalValue = response.ContentLength;
        long sum = 0;


        while ((read = rStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)) > 0 )
        {
            sum += read;

            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Progress = (int)((sum * 100) / totalValue)));


            try
            {
                streamToWriteTo.Write(data, 0, read);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        streamToWriteTo.Close();
        streamToWriteTo.Dispose();

        if (ModelLocator.HomeStatic.Downloads.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (Download d in ModelLocator.HomeStatic.Downloads)
            {
                if (d.State == DownloadState.Pending)
                {
                    d.State = DownloadState.InProgress;
                    d.StartDownload();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ConvertDownloadToTrack(this)));

        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ModelLocator.HomeStatic.Downloads.Remove(this)));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)));
            return;
        }
    }
```

This code works perfect with direct links, but it doesn't with the mp3clan.audio, here is an example of link, I Have tested this link and it seems to redirect to two websites before returning the file (i'm not sure):

http://mp3clan.audio/dl.php?type=get&s=4094c84c1a0a7fd0b53e556bb28ceb00&tid=4470600_45874963&name=Mp3NameGoesHere

Can someone point me to the right direction? Thanks for reading.